# Running Query Against SQLite3 Database Thru Powershell

Tags: powershell

currently i'm attempting to pull the users from a table in my SQLite3 database. Then i'd like to just have all the values (emails) stored in a variable. The issue i'm having is I just can't seem to get it to actually run the SQL statement and return the data.

Currently I have the following below, but if you have any suggestions let me know.  I don't know if it's the path to my database or not. I'm able to access it using the Go.DB file in DB Browser.

```
Install-Module -Name PowerADO.NET
Import-Module PowerADO.net

$cn = new-object system.data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\Go\go.db");
$cn.Open()
$q = @"
SELECT [email],* FROM [main].[results] ORDER BY [email];
"@
$da = new-object System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand ($q, $cn) # ($q, $cn)

$da.Fill
write-output $da
```

Comment: does the PowerADO module have any built in support for SQLite? do you have anything that ADO could use to talk to your SQLite database?

Comment: The PowerADO module does have SQLite support. I'll have to look into the talking to the SQLite database tho. I'll get back to you.

Comment: i'm ignorant of all the DB stuff, but i recall reading that you need to make sure your ADO setup is actually connecting. i can't recall how to do that, tho. [*blush*]

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, I appreciate it.

Comment: when you get an answer - even if YOU are the one who finds it - you can post that as an "answer" and upvote it. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

So I ended up switching modules to get this to work.

```
Install-Module PSSQLite
Import-Module PSSQLite
#Get-Command -Module PSSQLite

$Database = "C:\redacted\redacted.db"

$query = "SELECT [email],* FROM [main].[results] ORDER BY [email];"

$emaildata = Invoke-SqliteQuery -DataSource $Database -Query $query | Select email
write-output $emaildata
```